# Ionic 3 - Async Http Calls and Ionic Loading Issue

Tags: angularjs, http, promise, loading, ionic3

I would like to have some help about using Ionic `LoadingController` while having multiple HTTP calls that are processed in an async function.

Firstly, this is my async function with promises

```
LoadDatafromUrls(urLs) {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      let loader = this.loadingCtrl.create({
        content: 'Son Bilgiler Alınıyor',
      });
      var urlCalls = [];
      urLs.forEach((entry: any) => {
        loader.present().then(()=>{
          this.http.get(entry.url).map((response : Response)=>{
            console.log(response.json());
            urlCalls.push(response.json());
          }).subscribe(()=>{
            console.log("subscribe");
          });
          loader.dismiss();
        })
      })
      Promise.resolve(urlCalls).then((res)=>{
        console.log(res);
        resolve(res);
      },
      (res)=>{
        reject(res);
      })
      //return Promise;
    })
  }
```

Secondly, I call it in this way.

```
RequestObject.LoadDatafromUrls(urLs).then((results)=>{
        console.log(results);
      },
      (errors)=>{
        console.log(errors);
      })
```

In this method, I am having the error message below :

Error message: `Uncaught (in promise): removeView was not found`. Moreover, it does not work in the way I am expecting.

I am really open to completely new methods, new ways. Please share if I can have any better implementation.

Answer (score 0):

Because you are hiding the loader every time after getting a response from each call. Ionic throws this error when it tries to dismiss a loader but there is no loader on the view. Just dismiss the loader only after all calls has been resolved

```
 loader.present();
 urLs.forEach((entry: any) => {
     //   loader.present().then(()=>{
          urlCalls.push(this.http.get(entry.url).map((response : Response)=>{
            console.log(response.json());
            return response.json();
          }).subscribe(()=>{
            console.log("subscribe");
          }).toPromise());
         // loader.dismiss();
        })
     // })
 Promise.all(urlCalls).then((res)=>{
        console.log(res);
        resolve(res);
        loader.dismiss()
      },
      (res)=>{
        reject(res);
      })
```

**EDIT :
 How to use resolve multiple observables?**

```
    getData(urls){
     var loader = this.loadingCtrl.create({
       content : "Loading..."
     });
     loader.present();
     this.LoadDatafromUrls(urls).subscribe(res=>{
        console.log(res)//array of responses
        loader.dismiss();
     },err=>{
        console.log(err);// it will fire if any one call fails
        loader.dismiss();
      }); 
    }
    LoadDatafromUrls(urls){
     var arrObservables = [];         
     for(var i = 0; i < urls.length; i++){
         arrObservables.push(this.http.get(urls[i]).map((res: Response)=>{
           return res.json()
         }).catch((err: Response)=>{
           return Observable.throw(err);
         }))
     }
     return Observable.forkJoin(arrObservables);
    }
```

**Remember :** Add these import statement in your component :

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/forkJoin'
```

Comment: I am trying the way you mentioned above. i ll edit this comment about the feedback. Thanks !

Comment: It only shows itself like 2-3 seconds and then disappears how many url as i put. Besides, i have put only one url that retrieves 12mb data and its imposibble to get it in 2-3 seconds but it disappears again in 2-3 seconds.

Comment: The problem is that it get inside the scope of : 

Promise.resolve(urlCalls).then((res)=>{
        console.log(res);
        resolve(res);
        loader.dismiss()
      },
      (res)=>{
        reject(res);
      })

while the request is alive i mean its pending or retrieving data.

It should first get the data from call and then, gets into Promise.resolve function... I am so confused why it gets there before http call ends

Comment: The problem with your code was you were resolving the urlCalls which was an empty array. I have edited the code

Comment: Cannot use "toPromise()" function. It does not recognize it and can you also help me about where i should declare the empty array.

Comment: It should recognize toPromise() method, r u using the @angular/http module? Declare the empty array before loader.present()

Comment: Yes i have added. I can only add toPromise() method, if i remove subscribe() method. If i remove subscribe, then it does not do any ajax call. And btw, this function does not work as async. I tried also with your method "Promise.all(urlCalls)..." . It still the same, it goes inside the Promise before doing the call. I cant figure it out why. My goal is to have proper way to download the data from multiple urls, this was so simple in angular 1.

Comment: You should use observable with subscribe. And to resolve multiple observables use forkJoin operator

Comment: Can you please demonstrate it ?

Comment: Thank you so much sir ! Will check as soon as possible.

Comment: I am using the functions like this :

this.RequestObject.getData(urLs);

And i have the error below:

Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND file:///android_asset/www/[object%20Object]